# div gets hidden because of toggle function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a Div called `closeknop` and when clicked on, I want to give `menu` some `.css` styling, but when i use `.click` on `closeknop` it overrules my css display expression.

while i want `closeknop` to be visible when the screensize is less then  `989px` using a `media only screen` with `display:block` it gets `display:none` and when i want it to be hidden, outside of the `media only` it gets `display:block` while i set `display:none`.

So, to fix my problem i tried debugging with `console.log()` but my javascript runs only the first bit, but when i change `.toggle()` to `.click()` it does run but ofcource only once when clicked.

My question is: Am i doing something wrong using `.toggle()` in this javascript?

jsfiddle with both `.click and .toggle`:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrwk8z0p/2/)

Code:

```js
$(function(){
    let menu = ('.nav-nav');
    console.log('nou')
    $(".closeknop").toggle(function() {
        console.log('nee gewoon niet');
        $(menu).css('height', '300px');
    }, function() {
        $(menu).css('height', '0');
    });



});
```

```css
.closeknop{
    display:none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 989px){
  .closeknop{display:block;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="closeknop"></div>
```

Comment: [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) no longer accepts multiple function handlers to be run in sequence on each successive click. It was removed in jQuery 1.9. If you want that behaviour you will need to re-create the logic manually.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can i find the new toggle() behaviour in javascipt documentation?

Comment: Sure, http://api.jquery.com/toggle, but it only shows/hides a set of elements. It does not behave in a manner you require. Depending on the animation you want I'd suggest trying `slideToggle()` instead

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah i have seen api.jquery.com/toggle but i was like, this is not really how i want it to behave, ill try slideToggle() instead, thanks.

Comment: You should use `visibility: visible|hidden` in your CSS instead of changing the display.

Comment: @Mth no, i don't want to have my div take up space when not visible.

Comment: You could change the height also when hidden using `:visible` or `:hidden`.

Comment: jQuery changes the visibility in it's `show()`, `hide()` and `toggle()` functions.

Answer (score 1):

This was the final solution:
Thanks to @RoryMcCrossan

```js
$(function(){
    let menu = ('.nav-nav');
    console.log('ja');
    $(".closeknop").click(function() {
        console.log('hoi');
        $(menu).toggle( "slow" );
    });
});
```